# How or where put the code for Fluid Player

Tags: wordpress, iframe, embedded-resource

I recently installed Fluid Player plugin to my WordPress site. I can set the example video. But I need to set the embedded video through the iframe of the original page.

Documentation mentions that I need to set `<video>` in the `<body>` but in other place it says I need to add a shortcode in any new post.

I need your help to know in where of these places (new post or `<body>`) I have to set my player and how do I need to set the "src=" using the iframe

Comment: Both is correct, because the shortcode does exactly that: it adds the video code to the body. See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

Comment: Thanks @jasie. In my case, do you know how I can display a video using the iframe with this player? I'm able to display the sample video, but not embeded videos :(